# Proving that a cyclic permutation has subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is my own work, I'm "self-learning" and trying to give Algebra some much needed attention.

I've defined a permutation as follows:

Let X be the set {1,2,3,...,n}

Let f be a permutation on X.

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r$ for $1\le r\le n$ be distinct elements of X.

If we have:

- $x_rf=x_1$
- $x_if=x_{i+1}$ for $1\le i<r$
- $\forall y\in X\text{complement}\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}$ we have $yf=y$

Then I call f a "cycle" or "cyclic permutation" written as $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)$

I now want to link this definition with compositions. **I know $<S_n,\composition>$ is a group** $S_n$ denotes the set of all permutations on a set of length n ($X$)

Let $A=\{a,af,af^2,\dots,af^n\}$ where $a\in X$ (it can be any member of X)

There are only n members of X yet $|A|=n+1$, so we have a duplicate.

Reading from right to left and writing $a=af^0$ suppose $af^i$ is the first duplicate.

We can now be sure $\exists j\in\mathbb{N}:0\le j<i\ \text{and}\ af^j=af^i$

Applying the permutation $f^{-j}$ to both sides:

$a=af^{i-j}$

This is where I get stuck. Somehow I need to show $j=0$ (or can be equal to 0) so I may get to:

A comprises of the distinct elements $a,af,\dots,af^{i-1}$.

I imagine this as a kind of "orbit" of the element $a$, as $i$ is some unit of "how long" until $a$ comes back around. This is a nice word as there may be other cycles in the permutation (if my $(x_1,\dots,x_r)$ and another cyclic permutation are disjoint, the "orbits" are totally separate. It really is a nice word!)

Anyway, the orbit need not be of length n. I don't feel happy progressing without being able to finish this proof. I am certain it is true! If this wern't true then there'd always be a smaller $i$ contradicting that $i$ is the smallest to repeat. I think, this is (pardon the pun) circular though and I don't consider this a proof!

Comment: google `abstract algebra notes` there are *hundreds* of complete algebra courses for you ([1](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/), [2](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra), [3](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/)).  It's not like when I did this type of search in 1998.

Comment: @johnmangual I am following a book, I just want to do it with as little being spoonfed by it as I can! I did look ahead in this case and it says "by the minimality of i" which I don't follow.

Comment: which book are you following?  it would help to state the theorem you are trying to prove.  someone may have asked it here on math.SE already.

Comment: @johnmangual it's the footwork between theorems but if it is important: Rings Fields and Groups, an introduction to abstract algebra, second edition, R. B. J. T. Allenby, top of page 198.

Comment: your question can get an answer if you *state* the "footwork" you are trying to prove.  This is good for you to clarify it for *yourself*.

Comment: If $j > 0$, then $i - j < i$, so $a = af^{i-j}$ would be a duplicate before $i$, but $i$ was assumed to be the first duplicate

Comment: I wish to show that: A comprises of the distinct elements $a,af,\dots,af^{i−1}$, but I cannot make the jump from there exists a j to "by the minimality of i we see j=0"

Comment: Thanks @user115654, that's superb.